# Writing a program that outputs two mirroring triangles on top of each other in Java

Tags: java

I am supposed to write a program that will output two mirroring triangles on top of each other.

So far I only got the first one and I do not know how to go about with the second one.
This is my code so far.

```
public class Triangles {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        printTriangle();
    }
    public static void printTriangle () {
        //defines counting variable 
        int counting = 1;
        //defines rows 
        for(int rows = 0; rows < 5; rows++) 
        {
            int columns;
            for(columns = 0; columns < counting; columns++) {
                System.out.print("#");
            }
            counting = counting + 1;
            System.out.print("\n");
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: draw one by hand, using # or dots in a coordinate grid. Write down the coordinates, and then ask yourself how you need to use loops to get to that outcome. Remember that loops can also count downwards!

Comment: how the output shall look like?

Comment: The output I need does not paste well. It is supposed to be one right triangle and then a left triangle below.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Triangle {
        public static void main (String[] args) {
            printTriangle();
        }
        public static void printTriangle () {
            //defines counting variable
            int counting = 1;
            //defines rows
            for(int rows = 0; rows < 5; rows++) {
                {
                    int columns;
                    for(columns = 0; columns < counting; columns++) {
                        System.out.print("#");
                    }
                    counting = counting + 1;
                    System.out.print("\n");
                }
            }
            int countingBack = 5;
            for(int rows = 0; rows < 5; rows++) {
                {
                    int columns;
                    for(columns = counting; columns >1 ; columns--) {
                        System.out.print("#");
                    }
                    counting--;
                    System.out.print("\n");
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The triangle is not supposed to be upside down, I worded my question wrong, I am sorry. There has to be a space between the two triangles and the lower one should be straight, but facing the other way. Reverse.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Triangle {
        public static void main (String[] args) {
            printTriangle();
        }
        public static void printTriangle () {
            //defines counting variable
            int counting = 1;
            //defines rows
            for(int rows = 0; rows < 5; rows++) {
                {
                    int columns;
                    for(columns = 0; columns < counting; columns++) {
                        System.out.print("#");
                    }
                    counting = counting + 1;
                    System.out.print("\n");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            for(int rows = 1; rows <= 5; rows++) {
                {
                    for(int columns = 0; columns < 5 ; columns++) {
                        if (columns >= (5-rows))
                            System.out.print("#");
                        else
                            System.out.print(" ");
                    }

                    System.out.print("\n");
                }
            }
        }
}
```